# Where is the Increment method on the DataCache?

Tags: appfabric, appfabric-cache

I want to use the [Increment method from the DataCache documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613637.aspx) but the method is not available on my DataCache object. Clearly I don't have the version of Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client.dll that matches the documentation but I can't seem to figure out what version contains that method and where to get the assembly???

The version I have 1.0.4632.0

I am using the AppFabric for Windows 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is part of Azure and not Windows Server. AppFabric exists in two versions : one for Windows Server and one for Azure. There are only a few differences (here is one of them).

If you're targeting Azure, simply add the package [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/). You will find a detailed introduciton [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cache/net/how-to-cache-service/).

It you're targeting Windows Server, do it by yourself !

Comment: Actually, I figured this out late Friday and I implemented my own increment method already. :-)